# Populando banco de dados com Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um banco de dados com algumas tabelas já populadas, mas agora tenho que popular as tabelas que possuem chave estrangeira, estou tentando assim:

```
$tamanho = Tamanho::find(2);
$genero = Genero::find(1);
$categoria = Categoria::find(2);
$estampa = Estampa::find(1);
$pedido = Pedido::find(1);

$produto = new Produto;
$produto->descricao = 'Lançamento 2012';
$produto->tamanhos()->associate($tamanho);
$produto->generos()->associate($genero);
$produto->categorias()->associate($categoria);
$produto->estampas()->associate($estampa);
$produto->quantidade = '120';
$produto->vunitario = '50';
$produto->save();

$produto->pedidos()->save($pedido);
$pedido->produtos()->save($produto);
```

mas me retorna o erro:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()

#### model Produto:

```
class Produto extends Eloquent
{
// Produtos has_many Tamanhos
public function tamanhos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Tamanho');
}

// Produtos has_many Generos
public function generos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Genero');
}

// Produtos has_many Estampas
public function estampas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Estampa');
}

// Produtos belongs_to Categorias
public function categorias()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Categoria');
}

// Produtos belongs_to_many Pedidos
public function pedidos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Pedido');
}
```

}

O que pode estar errado?

Comment: Em qual linha acontece esse erro? Seria bom se pudéssemos ver o código-fonte do model Produto (para vermos as definições das relações entre os modelos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Nova Resposta:

A resposta original está mantida ao final. Ela estaria correta caso a relação fosse mesmo `hasMany`...

Mas o que está errado é justamente a definição da relação no modelo! Do jeito que o `hasMany` está sendo empregado, entende-se que um produto pode ter vários tamanhos, vários gêneros, e várias estampas. Mas pertence a UMA CATEGORIA SÓ (devido ao `belongsTo`).

Basta **corrigir as relações nos modelos** que o código usando `associate` vai funcionar do jeitinho que está!

```
class Produto extends Eloquent
{
    // Produto belongs to Tamanho
    public function tamanho()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Tamanho');
    }
}

class Tamanho extends Eloquent
{
    // Tamanhos has many Produtos
    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Produto');
    }
}
```

Faça as correções nos demais relacionamentos.

#### Resposta Original

O método `associate` vai funcionar para associações `belongsTo`.

No seu caso, você parece estar tentando usá-lo numa relação `hasMany`.

---

Toda relação `belongsTo` ("pertence a") é **singular**. Por exemplo, "endereço" e "usuário". O endereço pertence a **um** usuário. Portanto, posso usar o `associate`:

```
$usuario = Usuario::find(3);
$endereco = Endereco::find(9);
$usuario->endereco()->associate($endereco);

// onde "endereco" BELONGS TO "usuario"
```

Já uma relação `hasMany` ("tem vários")  é **plural**. O `associate` não vai funcionar - pois você só pode associar **um objeto** com o "associate", e não **uma coleção** ou vários objetos.

---

Numa relação `hasMany`, faça a associação pelo outro elemento, o elemento que `belongsTo`, assim:

```
$produto = new Produto;
$produto->descricao = 'Lançamento 2012';
$produto->quantidade = '120';
$produto->vunitario = '50';
$produto->save();

$tamanho->produto()->associate($produto)->save();
$genero->produto()->associate($produto)->save();
$categoria->produto()->associate($produto)->save();
$estampa->produto()->associate($produto)->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

consegui popular fazendo isso:

```
$produto = new Produto;
$produto->descricao = 'Lançamento 2012';
$produto->tamanho_id = $tamanho->id;
$produto->genero_id = $genero->id;
$produto->categoria_id = $categoria->id;
$produto->estampa_id = $estampa->id;
$produto->quantidade = '120';
$produto->vunitario = '50';
$produto->save();

$produto->pedidos()->save($pedido);
$pedido->produtos()->save($produto);
```

no final tenho uma pivot table que armazena o produto_id e i pedido_id, porque assim consigo fazer uma consulta aos produtos de um determinado pedido e deixa o bd mais organizado...

mas não tenho certeza se é correto o que fiz...
o que você acha???

Comment: eu fiz a partir de exemplos do livro codebright

Comment: Isso é uma pergunta ou uma resposta? Você precisa se acostumar que aqui não é igual a um fórum. Cada post não deve ser uma mensagem nova em uma thread de discussão. Quando você tem informações adicionais, edite sua pergunta. Deixe a resposta apenas quando você achou uma solução final. Aí todo mundo pode se beneficiar dela e você pode até aceitá-la se for o melhor que você achou. Mas se quer complementar a pergunta, edite a **pergunta**

Comment: @henrique: isso mesmo, é como o bigown falou; vamos aprendendo a manter este site bem produzido e bem cuidado; aproveite para aceitar a minha resposta a esta pergunta caso julgue correta... assim eu também ganho uns pontinhos e me mantenho motivado em ajudar! ;-)