# Consulta em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Como seria um exemplo de consulta a um bd com tabelas relacionadas e uma inserção de dados nelas.

Tenho as tabelas :

```
Produtos  
Tamanhos   
Generos
```

Preciso exibir na view `produtos.blade.php` uma lista com todos os produtos cadastrados e também seus campos `tamanho` e `genero` que estão identificados pelos seus id's na tabela `produtos`.

EDIT:

Eu postei o meu código dos models view e rota aqui: http://pastebin.com/MpqvxZay

lá tem os erros que estão retornando

```
//model Produto
<?php
class Produto extends Eloquent
{
        // Produtos has_many Tamanhos
        public function tamanhos()
        {
                return $this->hasMany('Tamanho');
        }
}

//model tamanho
<?php
class Tamanho extends Eloquent
{
        public $timestamps = false;

        // Tamanhoss belongs_to Produtos
        public function produtos()
        {
                return $this->belongsTo('Produto');
        }
}


//route com o eloquent
Route::get('/teste', function()
{
        $produtos = Produto::all();
        return View::make('produto.teste', compact("produtos"));
});


//foreach da view
 @foreach($produtos as $produto)
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{ $produto->tamanho->descricao }}" name="title" /></td>
                </tr>
 @endforeach


//Erro exibido na tela
Trying to get property of non-object

/* se eu mudo no foreach da view $produto->tamanho->descricao por $produto->tamanhos->descricao
me dá esse erro:
*/
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tamanhos.produto_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tamanhos` where `tamanhos`.`produto_id` = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, ))



sendo que na tabela produtos tem o campo tamanho_id para servir como chave estrangeira com a tabela tamanhos
```

Comment: Você quer um exemplo no banco ou em php ?

Comment: tipo um app no github :) que ai eu poderia ver como foi feito...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja, Henrique... respondi outra pergunta tua hoje... mas só agora percebi várias coisas... você não está definindo as relações corretamente. Temos que "voltar um pouco" e pensar melhor:

1º - Você tem um esquema no banco de dados, certo? Até onde eu vi, na tua tabela "produtos" você tem um campo "tamanho_id". Neste caso, isto está definindo uma relação **one-to-many** ("um para muitos"), onde UM TAMANHO pode ser atribuído a MUITOS PRODUTOS (e simultaneamente **many-to-one**, onde VÁRIOS PRODUTOS podem ter UM ÚNICO TAMANHO).

2º - No teu modelo, você define uma propriedade "tamanhos", e uma relação `hasMany`. Isso está **errado**. Isso só estaria certo se **UM PRODUTO pudesse ter VÁRIOS TAMANHOS**. O jeito certo de colocar a relação que você quer, nos modelos, é o seguinte:

```
//model Produto
<?php
class Produto extends Eloquent
{
    // Produto belongs to Tamanho
    public function tamanho()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Tamanho');
    }
}

//model tamanho
<?php
class Tamanho extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    // Tamanho has many Produtos
    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Produto');
    }
}
```

Uma vez que os modelos estejam corrigidos e coerentes com o esquema do banco de dados, você pode usar o método `with` para evitar que um novo "SELECT" seja executado a cada interação no LOOP que vai exibir os produtos na *view*. Por exemplo:

```
//route com o eloquent
Route::get('/teste', function()
{
    $produtos = Produto::with('tamanho', 'genero')->get();
    return View::make('produto.teste', compact("produtos"));
});
```

Por fim, a *view* vai funcionar do jeito que está:

```
@foreach($produtos as $produto)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="{{ $produto->tamanho->descricao }}" name="title" /></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @henrique: atualizei a resposta de tua pergunta anterior; confira - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4785/4707

Comment: agora não entendi o porque de dar erro quando uso tamanhos ao invés tamanho... prq asim eu axo que fica melhor de eu entender

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando o `Eloquent`, basta definir as relações no **model** `produtos` e o Laravel faz a mágica pra você.

No seu model de produtos, use o seguinte código de fazer a ligação:

```
public function tamanho()
{
     //Aqui deve ser posto o nome do model para a tabela tamanho.
     return $this->belongsTo('tamanho'); 
}
```

... o mesmo deve ser feito para `generos`.

Uma vez feito isso, basta iterar sobre a lista de produtos (com um `foreach`, por exemplo) e acessar diretamente as informações das tabelas relacionadas como se fossem atributos próprios do objeto `produto`.

```
$produto->tamanho->valor
```

...por exemplo, é uma forma de acessar o campo `valor`, contido na tabela `tamanho` através do objeto `produto`.

O Eloquente é simplesmente uma das coisas mais lindas que já vi dentro do mundo PHP. ;D

... espero que ajude!

**EDITE 1:**

Se teu `produtos` tem uma chave estrangeira para `tamanhos`, então a relação não é `hasMany` e sim `belongsTo`.

Comment: fiz as relações no model produtos, tamanhos e generos... vou tentar aqui agora a sua dica, se eu fiz tudo certo vai da certo hehehe...  qualquer coisa se der erro posso postar os models no pastebin.com

Comment: Poste aqui mesmo, não é bom gerar dependências de sites externos. Edite a sua pergunta, marque o número da Edição e dá tudo certo! ;)

Comment: postei ai Dennis Braga...

Comment: Cara, posta como edite da tua pergunta e não como resposta, por que, bem, não é uma resposta. Edita a tua pergunta (como eu fiz ali) e coloca esse mesmo texto lá!

Comment: agora sim... hehehe...  tô aprendendo usar ainda :)

Comment: GALERA VALEW MESMO.....   ME AJUDOU BASTANTE....  VCS SÃO FERAS MESMO... VLW